# Find replicates/duplicates in a vector in R

Tags: r

This is a very simple one. I have a vector containing replicates of two different values. I want to calculate the sum of replicates of each value.
An example of my vector:

```
> m <- c(rep(420,20), 421,rep(420,5),421,420,420,421,421,rep(420,3))
> m
 [1] 420 420 420 420 420 420 420 420 420 420 420 420 420 420 420 420 420 420 420 420 421 420 420 420 420 420 421
[28] 420 420 421 421 420 420 420
```

My vector contains lots of consecutive values of 420.
I used the function `rle()`:

```
> rle(m)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:7] 20 1 5 1 2 2 3
  values : num [1:7] 420 421 420 421 420 421 420
```

This gives me number of replicates but it gives the replicates one by one. How to calculate how many consecutive 420s are in my vector?

Let's say i have another vector

```
> n <- c(1,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,4,5,1,1,1,6,5,6) 
> n  [1] 1 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 4 5 1 1 1 6 5 6
> with(rle(n), tapply(lengths, values, FUN = sum))
 1 2 3 4 5 6  
 7 2 2 1 2 2
```

Here it says there are seven 1s. But actually there are 5 consecutive 1s.How to calculate that one?

Comment: Are you looking for `table(m)`?

Comment: @AllanCameron Not exactly. I'm only looking for consecutive replicates. I edited the question and add a second vector example. That shows my problem better.

Comment: How do you get 5 consecutive 1s with the data 'n'

Comment: Can you show the calculation for that 5 1s.  I didn't get the logic for that

Comment: @akrun I just count 1s that are together. There are seven 1s in total. But there are two consecutive groups of 1 in the n. (1,1) and (1,1,1). So I summed them and its 5. Sorry for bad explanation.

Comment: @user14316891 then you `table(rle(m)$values)`

Comment: @user14316891 i think you may need `with(rle(n), sum(rep(values[lengths > 1], lengths[lengths > 1])))`

Comment: @user14316891 i updated the post.  Please check if that helps. thanks

Comment: @akrun `> with(rle(n), sum(rep(values[lengths > 1], lengths[lengths > 1])))
[1] 5
> with(rle(m), sum(rep(values[lengths > 1], lengths[lengths > 1])))
[1] 13442` It worked for n. But it did not work for m

Comment: Please check my output below.  It gives 30 and 2 as values.  The function you are using is not complete.  I updated the funciton in my post

Comment: @akrun Yeah I saw it now. It works great! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the  `rle` output, we can do a group by operation with `tapply`

```
lst1 <-  within.list(rle(m), {i1 <- lengths > 1
        lengths <- lengths[i1]
         values <- values[i1]})

with(lst1, tapply(lengths, values, FUN = sum))
#   420 421 
#  30   2
```

---

For the vector `n`

```
lst1 <-  within.list(rle(n), {i1 <- lengths > 1
        lengths <- lengths[i1]
         values <- values[i1]})

with(lst1, tapply(lengths, values, FUN = sum))
#1 
#5
```